# How to easily escape a command-line filter

Tags: vim, escaping

I've seen discussions about performing pipes in Vim of the type

```
:%! cmd1 | cmd2 | ...
```

And it works with `:w` as well

```
:.w !cat | cat
```

And it works with `:r`

```
:r !echo hello | cat
:r !ls | grep .mp4
```

But the second I try something more ambitious, like, say, `awk`, it stops working:

```
:r !ls | awk '{printf "\"%s\"\n", $0}'
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"
```

I have tried dozens of variations on the syntax to get it to work, including surrounding the entire command-line after `!` with `()`, but it just refuses to work saying something about an Empty file name. That's what led me to search on Google and find out whether or not piping actually works in Vim. Thing is, it's not a problem with awk. Here's what happens with that same exact command-line on a bash shell:

```
$ ls | awk '{printf "\"%s\"\n", $0}'
"somefile1"
"somefile2"
"somefile3"
"somefile4"
```

It also works in `sh` (or `dash` on my system).

How do I make vim stop misinterpreting my input? Actually, I just figured out the solution to the specific problem that spurred this question on. You have to escape the `%` so it doesn't interpret it as the name of the opened file.

```
:r !ls | awk '{printf "\"\%s\"\n", $0}'
                         ^
```

However, this is still annoying behavior (and confusing IMO, Vim's escape for `%` looks just like awk's escapes; how is one supposed to know that doing that won't cause awk to output literally `"%s"\n`? It was a wild guess on my part).

I would like to know if there's a way to totally escape a `filter` (the part after the `!`) so that I don't have to slowly parse what I just wrote and special-case it just for Vim. Over-complicated escaping quickly gets unreadable and is one of my pet peeves when it comes to meta-programming.

*Surely* there must be a simple way to tell Vim to ignore characters like `%` et al, and pass them to the shell as-is, so that I can test my commands on the shell and copy/paste them into Vim without having to worry about manually escaping specific characters, because I can imagine that easily becoming a huge pain in the ass.

And actually, this has been a bit of an XY problem. I'll have to post the original problem in a different question, though, because the `Y` question is really interesting and I would like to know. I'll post a link to the `X` question in the comments.

Comment: Here's the `X` question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49619411/1175714

Comment: The part after the `!` is not a "filter"; it's just a regular external command that doesn't act like a filter at all. Anyway, see `:help shellescape()`.

Comment: @romainl I call it a filter because that's literally what vim calls it, `:help !` -> `:{range}![!]{filter} [!][arg]`. It's *not* a filter when called via `:r/w`, but it would be confusing if I were switching between two different terminologies over a technicality.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for the pointer. I'll check it out.

Comment: No. What Vim calls a filter is specifically what's covered under `:help filter`, ie an actual filter. Your question is about `:r`, `:help :r` doesn't call the command a filter, you don't use the command as a filter, so there's no reason to call it a filter.

Comment: @romainl Right, I get what you're saying, but I did mention `:%!cmd1 | cmd2 | ...` first, and at the time had only read `:help !`, assuming the terminology would be the same. I *would* edit the question, but as I said, I don't want to confuse potential answerers. Although I *would* be willing to edit if it were to change every mention of "filter" to "command", just not both. I want to keep the question simple and concise. Anyways, I tried the following: `:exe 'r !' . shellescape("ls | awk '{printf \"\\\"%s\\\"\", $0}'")`. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts at using `shellescape()` are close. What you're missing:

- For `:!` (and `:r !`), you need to pass `1` for the `{special}` flag to it.
- You can only escape a single command-line argument with it, not the entire command-line. As you only have critical characters in the last (`awk` script) argument, we only need it there:

```
:exe 'r ! ls | awk ' . shellescape('{printf "\"%s\"\n", $0}', 1)
```

Comment: While your answer satisfies the question, I have to ask: What does `1` do and why is this not the default behavior? That's my immediate reaction. I looked it up and the `1` apparently tells the function to escape characters. So not only do we have a boolean argument where we have to look up the documentation to understand what it does, but it leaves the user wondering why it isn't the default behavior for a function named `shellescape` to *escape* the given string. This is like `deleteEmployee("Bob", false, true)`. Sometimes, the stupid/insane design choices in vimL blow my mind.