# How to disambiguate vim commands from shell commands

Tags: vim, filter, escaping

From [How to easily escape a command-line filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619265/how-to-easily-escape-a-command-line-filter):

> And actually, this has been a bit of an XY problem. I'll have to post the original problem in a different question, though, because the Y question is really interesting and I would like to know. I'll post a link to the X question in the comments.

This is the "X" question.

I had thought that by figuring out how to escape the `%`, I would solve the problem, but it turns out Vim's behavior goes deeper than I had thought. And that is that apparently, Vim has some special meaning for `|` in its own scripting language, which complicates things:

```
:nmap L :r !ls | awk '{printf "\"\%s\"\n", $0}'<CR>
```

**Expected result**:

Pressing `L` fills the buffer with the output of `ls`, with each line quoted.

**Actual result**:

```
E492: Not an editor command:  awk '{printf "\"\%s\"\n", $0}')<CR>
```

Vim seems to think by `awk`, I mean a vim command, rather than a shell command. How do I disambiguate this? I have tried many combinations, including surrounding the filter with a subshell, and putting a `!` in front of awk as well, but...

**Subshell:**

```
:nmap L :r !(ls | awk '{printf "\"\%s\"\n", $0}')<CR>
E492: Not an editor command:  awk '{printf "\"\%s\"\n", $0}')<CR>
```

**Subshell + `!awk`:**

```
:nmap L :r !(ls | !awk '{printf "\"\%s\"\n", $0}')<CR>
[No write since last change]
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `awk '{printf "\"%s\"\n", $0}')<CR>'    
shell returned 1    
Press ENTER or type command to continue
L
:r !(ls
```

**`!awk` without subshell:**

```
:nmap L :r !ls | !awk '{printf "\"\%s\"\n", $0}'<CR>
[No write since last change]
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `awk '{printf "\"%s\"\n", $0}'<CR>'
shell returned 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
L
:r !ls
```

I'm speechless.

Comment: Does replacing `|` with `\|` work?

Comment: @Ryan Yes! Darn, and I had actually *tried* that before, but if you look at the [Y problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619265/how-to-easily-escape-a-command-line-filter), you'll understand why it failed when I tried `:nmap L :r !ls \| awk '{printf "\"%s\"\n", $0}'<CR>`. That's why I hate getting hung up on syntax. Because you try a billion combinations, and then you learn something new, and have to remember every combination you tried before hand. It's maddening.

Comment: Did you try it with both `\|` and `\%`? You have `\%` in this question, but not in that comment.

Comment: My bad. I thought I had implied with "Yes!" that it worked. But re-reading it, I can see how it would parse as "Yes I did, damn you!" rather than "Yes! Thank you!".

Comment: Oh, I thought you were saying Y remained a problem. Glad to hear it.

Comment: Well, actually, the [Y problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619265/how-to-easily-escape-a-command-line-filter) does remain a problem, since it deals with broadly escaping, and it's something I would like to know for future convenience. But your solution solves the X problem (this question) nicely. Post the solution as an answer and you'll get a +1 from me for sure! You deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

[Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan) helpfully pointed out that I didn't try escaping the pipe. Something that had entirely slipped my mind:

```
:nmap L :r !ls \| awk '{printf "\"\%s\"\n", $0}'<CR>
               ^
```

It worked.

Now if we could just solve that [Y problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619265/how-to-easily-escape-a-command-line-filter), I would be a happy camper.

Comment: If Ryan posts an answer, I'll +1 and accept it by default. This answer is just here as a placeholder, if you will. I do not intend to take credit for his answer.